# htaccess RewriteEngine

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an url which is http://www.urlbookmarking.com/bookmarks-details.php?bid=55
and I want it to be like 
http://www.urlbookmarking.com/bookmark/55

I wrote in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /bid/(.*) bookmarks-details.php?bid=$1
```

But when I go to the first URL the rewrite engine does not apply my rule. Is there any mistake, or conflict somewhere?

My full htaccess file written as follows

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^urlbookmarking.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.urlbookmarking.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /bid/(.*) bookmarks-details.php?bid=$1
```

Please help me.

Comment: You didn't add the rewrittenn part. Or rather you got it backwards.

Comment: Will the book ID have any letters or will it always be all digits. What is the maximum amount of digits as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  line `Options +FollowSymLinks` is optional if already configured in **httpd.conf**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^urlbookmarking\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.urlbookmarking.com/$1 [R=301, L]

RewriteRule ^bookmark/([0-9]+)$ bookmarks-details.php?bid=$1 [NC, L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. `RewriteEngine On` only needs to called once, though this may not be causing any problems
2. I also have `RewriteBase /` after my `RewriteEngine On` line
3. My rewrite rule looks like this: `RewriteRule ^common/(.*)$ common.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]`, which tells me that your rule should looke like this `RewriteRule ^bookmark/(.*) bookmarks-details.php?bid=$1 [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 0):

1. you should use only one `RewriteEngine on`
2. `RewriteRule /bid/(.*) bookmarks-details.php?bid=$1` - put this line after `Options +FollowSymLinks`
3. Try again

Answer (score 0):

Do you want you url to be `/bid/55` or `/bookmark/55`? because you have written it as if it is going to be `/bid/55`...

Anyway, your .htaccess should look more like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^urlbookmarking.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.urlbookmarking.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^bid/(.*)$ bookmarks-details.php?bid=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

...without the multiple `RewriteEngine on` directives (these don't break anything but are unnecessary), and without the leading forward slash on the `bid` rewrite rule. Also, put your new rule before the rules that rewrites for non-existent file so it doesn't rewrite your URL before you get a chance to use it, and add a `[L]` flag to the rule so it doesn't get further modified by the other rules. Also, add the line start/end markers (`^`/`$`) to the rule.

You would only use the leading forward slash if you were putting the rules in `httpd.conf`, you don't use them in `.htaccess` files.

If you want your urls to be `/bookmark/`, just replace `bid` with `bookmark`.

Answer (score 0):

This should redirect all '/bookmarks-details.php\?bid=(id)' urls with bookmarks ids (that have only numbers) to /bookmark/(id).

```
RewriteRule ^/bookmarks-details\.php\?bid=([0-9]+) /bookmark/$1 [R, NC, L]
```

Once you successfully rewritten the URL, you then need to write a companion rule to process it, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^/bookmark/([0-9]+) /bookmarks-details\.php\?bid=$1 [NC, L]
```

If should go between the rule that always adds 'www' to the beginning and the catch all rule, which I placed at the end. All together, it may look like so:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^urlbookmarking.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.urlbookmarking.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/bookmarks-details\.php\?bid=([0-9]+) /bookmark/$1 [R, NC, L]
RewriteRule ^/bookmark/([0-9]+) /bookmarks-details\.php\?bid=$1 [NC, L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This link may make things clearer: http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php