# URL Rewriting in Apache Not Working For Me

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I am using WAMP and has created a website in a 'http://localhost/snap2/html' folder. I am trying to execute following Rewrite rule but this is not working for me.

Server is giving me an error below:

The requested URL /snap2/html/browsed.html was not found on this server.

My .htaccess file is located in html folder and its structure is as below:

`RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^decision/([0-9]+)$ /snap2/html/decision.php?PanelID=$1`

Website is in a structure like 'www/snap2/html

Infact I am trying to rewrite following url

http://localhost/snap2/html/decision.php?PanelID=20

in to

http://localhost/snap2/html/decision/20

Also Options +FollowSymLinks gives me an error 500 therefore, I have commented it.

Any help would be pretty much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your write `RewriteRule` twice. Try

```
RewriteRule decision/([0-9]+)$ /snap2/html/decision.php?PanelID=$1 [L, QSA]
```

Or

```
RewriteRule snap2/html/decision/([0-9]+)$ /snap2/html/decision.php?PanelID=$1 [L, QSA]
```

Comment: It gives me an error: The requested URL /snap2/html/decision/20 was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule RewriteRule ^snap2/html/decision/([0-9]+)$ /snap2/html/decision.php?PanelID=$1
```

But I guess this is not what you want. But maybe you will see where you wrong.

Comment: Thanks for writing. I have updated my question with little more information. Could you please look at that again?

Answer (score 0):

Symbol `^` in regular expression means that following string should be at the beginning of URL. so you have to include entire path, see [htaccess RewriteEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388974/htaccess-rewriteengine) for more examples