# redirect url in wordpress wp-admin dashboard via htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to redirect a url in my wordpress wp-admin dashboard from `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=for_buyers to wp-admin/for-buyers/`.

Is there any way to correctly do this? I've tried modifiying my `.htaccess` file as can be seen below, but it's not working.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/for-buyers/$ /wp-admin/admin.php?page=for_buyers
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

UPDATE: I have been able to do it, but it now causes a redirect loop.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/wp-admin/admin.php?page=for_buyers wp-admin/for-buyers/$
</IfModule>
```

Comment: why do you need this?

Comment: So I can have pretty urls in my wp-admin dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to redirect your url but just **rewrite it**.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388974/htaccess-rewriteengine)

Hope this helps you!